# Selenium - Multiple anchor - Same ID - Not able to fetch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on anchor tag whose class id is clsArrowClick and the same id is on another anchor tag.

```
<td class="text-center" style="width: 25% !important;">
<td class="arrow" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title="" 
style="width: 25% !important; text-align:center" data-original-
title="Select/Show Data">
**<a id="clsArrowClick" class="clsarrowClick" href="#" 
onclick="javascript:OpenAddNewWellPopup(this);">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"/>
</a>**
<input id="hdnIsSaved0" class="hdnIsArrowSaved" value="0" type="hidden"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td style="width:50%; class=" '="" data-container="body" data-
toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="abcd">abcd</td>
<td class="text-center" style="width: 25% !important;">
<td class="arrow" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title=""             
style="width: 25% !important; text-align:center" data-original-            
title="Select/Show Data">
**<a id="clsArrowClick" class="clsarrowClick" href="#" 
onclick="javascript:OpenAddNewPopup(this);">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"/>
</a>**
<input id="hdnIsSaved1" class="hdnIsArrowSaved" value="0" type="hidden"/>
</td>
```

**I tried list, wait method and simple way everything, but my program throws an error 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException**

Like

//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
             //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("clsArrowClick")));
             //driver.findElement(By.className("clsarrowClick"));
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='clsArrowClick'])[1]")).click();

Comment: 1. I observed there are 2 links with id="clsArrowClick" & class="clsarrowClick". One of them calls the JavaScript "OpenAddNewWellPopup(this)" & the other calls the JavaScript "OpenAddNewPopup(this)" So which one do you want to click ? 2. Can paste a bit more of the HTML DOM? 3. Please keep your HTML DOM formated so its easier for us to interpret.

Comment: I wanna click 1st one and thats all HTML I can supply

Comment: When you use findElement you will be returned the first element, no need to use index in xpath. You should use the visibilityofelementlocated() expectedcondiion.

Comment: Not directly related to question, but ask the developers to **FIX THE HTML**. `id`s should be *unique*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following xpaths might work for second link. I haven't tested that and I don't know the whole html of your page so I said might.

```
//a[@id='clsArrowClick'][2]
```

or this one

```
//input[@id='hdnIsSaved1']../a[@id='clsArrowClick']
```

or following if you are interested in clickin first link

```
//td[@class='arrow']/a[@id='clsArrowClick']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `presenceOfElementLocated` condition before finding the element. An important thing to note is that `presenceOfElementLocated` only checks for presence of element on DOM, irrespective of it's visibility. You need to make sure that the element you are fetching is visible, so for that you should use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`. `visibilityOfElementLocated` guarantees that the element is available on the DOM and also visible, so that will help in overcoming the `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException` you are facing.

So your code should look something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
           By.xpath("(.//*[@id='clsArrowClick'])[1]"))); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='clsArrowClick'])[1]")); //this step can be skipped
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='clsArrowClick'])[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by alessandro-da-rugna, the id should be unique and I think it should be fixed. Selenium also have limitation in terms of find element, if there are two or more elements, it will choose the first one that present, regardless it is visible or not, which click method requires the element to be visible and enabled

To solve this, there are several ways

1. Make sure your xpath is unique, so you get , for  example `//a[::following-sibling/input[@id='hdnIsSaved1']]` when you find element
2. As mentioned by jayesh Doolani, you could use

   WebElement myElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath())
   myElement.click()
3. The second way is to use find elements, then find which element that meet your criteria, by checking its attribute, and make sure element clickable, by checks the enable method. Then do click on element that match your criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"));
         js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
         js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
         element = null;
         js = null;
```